# Does any denomination have records of performing exorcisms on atheists?

Tags: history, denomination-survey, exorcism, atheism, demon-possession

Has an atheist, an agnostic, a [naturalist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naturalism_(philosophy)) or anyone lacking a belief in the supernatural for that matter ever been demon possessed or had a demonic experience of any kind? Is this even possible to begin with (theoretically speaking)? My personal opinion would be that this should be possible in principle: there is no middle ground, a soul either belongs to God or Satan. Therefore, if an atheist or agnostic openly denies or rejects the existence of God, their soul cannot belong to God (because they don't have Jesus Christ as their Lord and Savior), and since there are not more options, it follows that their soul must belong to Satan. And if they belong to Satan, I would imagine that there should be demonic spirits assigned to each atheist or agnostic, and it shouldn't be too far-fetched to think that these spirits might decide to make their presence more obvious if they are compelled or under pressure to do so (e.g. I'm picturing in my head a hypothetical scene where a spirit-filled missionary confronts an atheist and the demons inside the atheist suddenly begin to manifest, etc.).

Has this ever happened? Does any denomination have records of performing exorcisms on atheists?

Comment: You wrote: “My personal opinion would be that this should be possible in principle“ and I became suspicious you meant “should not be possible..”

Comment: Sinfulness (or temptation), and possession, are two distinct things, and that's assuming that our hypothetical atheist is sinful to begin with; if a man rejects the Old Testament for the abominations contained therein (ultimately a remnant of Judaism's pagan roots, Joshua 24:2), and Christianity for the atrocities committed throughout its history, is it really God he's rejecting ?

Comment: @AlBrown - I meant what I said, that it should be possible. In fact, I know [one person](https://youtu.be/usvp55bVy3o) who claims this happened to them, but this is far from being an officially recognized case by any denomination.

Comment: I believe St. Augustine of Hippo does an exorcism of someone who does not believe in Christianity. The only requirement he made is that the person earnestly study the faith afterwards.